# ts function in R

Tags: time-series

My time series data are separately by hourly. The length of time series is 1005 days. The start day is 2/04/2014 and the end day is 31/12/2016. I’m using R (3.1.1). I’d like to know the value of the “frequency” argument in the ts() function in R, for annual, seasons and month. Since most of the examples and cases I’ve seen so far are for months or days at the most. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a year has $365.25\times 24=8766$ hours, so to look at yearly seasonality for hourly data, you'd enter `frequency=8766`.

Months are a bit more complicated, since each month has a different number of hours. You could use $8766/12=730.5$.

You will need to be a bit more specific as to what you mean by "seasons", but the above may already answer your question here.

Or are you in fact interested in how to model *multiple* seasonalities at the same time, e.g., intra-daily and intra-yearly seasonalities? In that case, I'd recommend you look at the `msts` class in the `forecast` package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. OK, for now, I would like to apply the trend package, to apply the  Seasonal Mann-Kendall Test, I guess I should have my data somehow separated into seasons?!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the seasonal Mann-Kendall test, but it sounds like it will work with only one seasonality, right? So you can apply it to the intra-daily seasonality of hourly data, or the intra-yearly seasonality of the same hourly data. The first two paragraphs of my answer should cover this, right?

Answer (score 0):

The frequency argument depends on how your data is structured. For instance, you mention that your data is separated on an hourly basis. If you wanted to account for every observation in the time series, then your frequency would be an hourly frequency, i.e. 61320, since that is the number of hours in a year. Therefore, if you are defining by an hourly frequency, your ts() function would be set up as follows:

**Hourly**

`tsfunction <- ts(variable, frequency=61320, start=c(2014,2), end=c(2016,12))`

However, if you wanted to structure your data on a daily, monthly, or annual basis as you mentioned (and is a more standard way of doing so), you can accordingly set the function as follows:

**Daily**

`tsfunction <- ts(variable, frequency=24, start=c(2014,2), end=c(2016,12))`

The number of intervals per day (as it is measured on an hourly basis) is 24, so R is taking every 24 observations to create a daily time series.

**Monthly**

`tsfunction <- ts(variable, frequency=720, start=c(2014,2), end=c(2016,12))`

However, with the number of hours per month being 720 (assuming 30 days per month), then R is selecting the observation for every 720 entries, hence frequency=720.

**Annual**

There are 8760 hours in a year (365*24), so accordingly frequency is 8760:

`tsfunction <- ts(variable, frequency=8760, start=c(2014,2), end=c(2016,12))`

As another answer mentioned, please be more specific on what you mean by "seasons".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. OK, for now, I would like to apply the trend package, to apply the Seasonal Mann-Kendall Test, I guess I should have my data somehow separated into seasons?!

Comment: Well, in the first instance, you need to define how you wish to measure seasons. For instance, one dataset could show seasonality every 2 months, another every 12 months, etc. Have you identified the seasonality factor in your data?

Comment: I would like to measure seasons like "really" seasons. So, my data-set should show seasonality each 3 months. Or, could I apply the Mann-Kendall Test for each month?

Comment: Even though your data "should" show seasonality for every 3 months, doesn't necessarily mean it will. Seasonality is subjective to each time series, and despite the name does not necessarily fluctuate with each season. Have you looked at autocorrelations to identify the indicated time lag? You could use the test for each month as specified here: http://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/Vsample/Design_Trend_Seasonal_Kendall.htm. However, I would verify the nature of your seasonality first.